# Scp any 100 files and its corresponding xml files to a remote pc?

Tags: file-sharing, copy, scp

I have around `2000 images` in a folder.I need to `scp 100 or 'n'` no of files from the directory to a remote pc folder.I have the files as follows.

```
1. A.jpg
2.A.xml
3.B.jpg
4.B.xml.....

etc
```

How can i do it using `scp`. I need to move jpg and its correpsonding xml ...that is in total 200.

Comment: Possible method: zip the files and unzip them on the other side. Then delete there what you do not want. You can use wildcards in scp but if it takes longer than 10 minutes to create a collection don't waste your time and just zip the lot.

Comment: ok! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by :

```
scp -r -p server-user@server-adress:/path/to/your/photos /your/remote/destination/path
```

But if I understand you want to grab a part of those files? it must be more simple if your files are sorted... If your files are sorted as you describe (with alphabet), what is the filename of the 27th file?